# Quarkus Camel SFTP route Quartz schedule not starting

Tags: apache-camel, quarkus, quartz, camel-ftp

I have configured an SFTP Camel route with Quartz scheduling in a Quarkus v1.7.1 app. The app starts up without errors, but the Quartz schedule doesn't actually start because it thinks there is no work to be done.

My route is defined by

```
from("sftp://sftp.server.com:22/path?"
            + "binary=true&"
            + "streamDownload=true&"
            + "password=*****"
            + "username=user&"
            + "jschLoggingLevel=TRACE&"
            + "antInclude=*.zip&"
            + "scheduler=quartz&"
            + "scheduler.cron=0 0/5 00-23 * * ?")
            .to("file://c/Temp/");
```

In the log I see

```
[org.apa.cam.com.qua.QuartzComponent] (Quarkus Main Thread) Starting scheduler.
[org.qua.cor.QuartzScheduler] (Quarkus Main Thread) Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler-quarkus-camel-ftp_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
[io.qua.qua.run.QuartzScheduler] (Quarkus Main Thread) No scheduled business methods found - Quartz scheduler will not be started
```

I expected it to start and poll the FTP server every 5 minutes. But nothing happens. Is my assumption incorrect?

Comment: Those log messages are a bit misleading because they come from the Quarkus Quartz extension. Camel internally sets up its own scheduler. If you search the logs for `QuartzScheduledPollConsumerScheduler`, you should see the time for when the next poll will be fired.

Comment: I get that, but still nothing happens `Job QuartzScheduledPollConsumerScheduler.trigger (triggerType=CronTriggerImpl, jobClass=QuartzScheduledPollConsumerJob) is scheduled. Next fire date is ...`